# Is it safe to render a react portal into another component DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

Consider the following example:

```js
class GridContainer extends React.Component {
  ...
  render (){
    return <div>
      <Pagination portalId="portal-id"></>
      <Grid ...>
    </div>
  }
}

class Grid extends React.Component {
  ...
  render (){
    return <div>
      <div id="portal-id"></>
      <table ...>
    </div>
  }
}

class Pagination extends React.Component {
  ...
  render (){
    return return ReactDOM.createPortal(<div>Paginator DOM...</div>, document.getElementById(this.props.portalId));
  }
}
```

Is it safe to render a portal inside other components DOM? I've tested it and it works, but I don't know if this is reliable. The `Portals` doc mention that you can render a portal in a DOM node but nothing about components DOM.

Why is this different (speculating here)? while updating the portal parent component, in the reconciliation process the diff might find the inconsistency and remove the portal node.

From my testing, the above doesn't happen but I don't know if I can assume that react handles it. So here comes the Q:

Is it safe to render a portal into another component DOM?

Comment: You basically enforce old-fashioned jQuery style this way. This isn't desirable in React app.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Is it safe? Sure, but it probably won't work the way you expect.

**First off, you can totally dump dom inside a `div` that React created.**

I've met several React programmers who would contest this fact, but Reacts design expects and accounts for editing dom directly when necessary. If they didn't, there would be no `componentDidUpdate` or React `refs`.

[This documentation on integration with other libraries](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html) is probably the most relevant.

Here's the scoop:

- React won't touch the internals of a rendered div, assuming it's always empty at the end of render. It will only:

  - Create new elements, which is irrelevant here as long as you leave it empty.
  - Update existing elements that were originally created by react.
  - Delete elements that were originally created by react.

So just create that empty div and leave it alone in `render` and React won't mess with it.

**Here's the rub; React guarantees nothing about the timing of the renders.**

This means that you have no idea if the element will actually be there when `Pagination` renders, causing the query to fail and the portal to not display. `componentDidUpdate` only works because React specifically runs it *after* the dom is updated. But render is run *before* the dom is updated. So if `Pagination` is rendered in the same sweep as `Grid` that div is likely not mounted yet.

**Now the infamous stack overflow Just-Don't-Do-That answer:**

Just don't do that. The purpose of portal is to let you render outside the React container while keeping your components inside of Reacts render tree. If you're rendering inside React render tree anyways why don't you just render the components there? (if that statement is confusing I blame you)

Comment: Haha your just don't do that answer really answered my question. I may need to ask my own about what TO do lol, ie how to make my useModal or useToaster able to be called from anywhere and passed a component to render.

Answer (score 7):

> The Portals doc mention that you can render a portal in a DOM node but nothing about components DOM

This isn't mentioned because this is special case of general rule; DOM shouldn't be accessed directly in React if there are more idiomatic ways.

A lot of memory leaks occur in DOM. In case a component that hosts a portal (`Grid`) is re-rendered and portal component (`Pagination`) is not, this will result in detached DOM, i.e. memory leak.

An element where a portal is attached may not even exist at the time when portal component renders.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the opinion that `createPortal` should not be used to render one react component inside another. But if you need to, you can achieve similar result with `useState` and `useEffect`:

```js
const {createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect} = React

const PortalContext = createContext({
  portalContent: null,
  setPortalContent: () => {}
})

const PortalContextProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [portalContent, setPortalContent] = useState(null)

  return (
    <PortalContext.Provider value={{portalContent, setPortalContent}}>
      {children}
    </PortalContext.Provider>
  )
}

const usePortal = (renderContent, deps) => {
  const {setPortalContent} = useContext(PortalContext)

  useEffect(() => {
    setPortalContent(renderContent())
    return () => {
      setPortalContent(null)
    }
  }, [setPortalContent, ...deps])
}

const PortalSource = () => {
  usePortal(() => 'Hello there', [])

  return (
    <div>Portal Source</div>
  )
}

const PortalTarget = () => {
  const { portalContent } = useContext(PortalContext)

  return (
    <div>Portal Target: {portalContent}</div>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <PortalContextProvider>
      <h1>Demo</h1>
      <PortalSource />
      <PortalTarget />
    </PortalContextProvider>
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root')
).render(<App />)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```